# Dynamically generate SQL query based on selection in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table 1:

[image]

and table 2 :

[image]

Each question can have multiple choices (ex: questionId 1 has two choices choiceId 1 and 2).

I have a form which will allow users to select multiple choices like this:

[image]

There is also a table for answers:

[image]

Now my question is: I want to form a SQL query based on the selection and show the count of selected answers.(ex: I want count of answers having gender as female and education as grade 1). How do I do that?

I tried something like this:

```
select * from answers where (questId =2 and choiceIndex='2.0000') and (questId =3 and choiceIndex='1.0000') and someId=72
```

This query does not give me the correct count as same choiceIndex can exists for a different choice.

How can I achieve this? Also user can selected many choices from the form so is there any way by which I can dynamically generate my SQL query?

> **Eidt**

Thanks @Marc Gravell for the solution. It helped a lot. Now once I achieved this I want to include arithmetic operators in my query. (ex: I want count of answers having gender as female `+` education as grade 1 `-` education as grade3).

Is there a way by which I can include arithmetic operators(+, -, *, /, %, count, average) in my query?

Scenario:I have designed a form in which a user will generate formula from database values. (ex:user will select choice1[female] + choice2[grade 1] * choice3[grade3] and generate formula will be saved in DB for further use)

I tried like this:

```
 select ((select COUNT(*) from answers where (questId =2 and answer='1.0000') and someId=72) +
 (select COUNT(*) from answers where (questId =3 and answer='1.0000') and someId=72))
```

In this query I am trying to perform add operation on two select statements. In the same way can I do *,/,percentage etc?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: re the edit; yes the database can perform arithmetic operations, but it would require numeric inputs - it isn't clear what you mean *exactly* in your "like this" example

Comment: In that query I am trying to add count of 2 select queries. Same way I would like to perform other arithmetic operations. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it works. Just wondering if there's any other better way to do that.

Comment: no, that looks about right; you could also use: select count(1) from (query 1) union [all] (query 2) union [all] (query 3), but what you have is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choiceIndex` is **never** going to be `2.0000` and `1.0000` at the same time; I assume, therefore, that you mean:

```
select * from answers where (
    (questId=2 and choiceIndex='2.0000') or
    (questId=3 and choiceIndex='1.0000')
) and someId=72
```

Note that if you are building a query based on input values, you should probably parameterize it, so it ends up as:

```
select * from answers where (
    (questId=@questId0 and choiceIndex=@choiceIndex0) or
    (questId=@questId1 and choiceIndex=@choiceIndex1)
) and someId=@someId
```

having added parameters with values:

- `@questId0` => `2`
- `@questId1` => `3`
- `@choiceIndex0` => `'2.0000'`
- `@choiceIndex1` => `'3.0000'`
- `@someId` => `72`

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. It helped a lot. I have one more query, I have updated my question. Please take a look.